# onTapGesture and onLongPressGesture not responsive

Tags: swiftui

I have a SwiftUI button where initially I handled the button-press inside the action area, but now I want to change the button so that I can also long press it. In order to do this, I now have to create an onTapGesture and onLongPressGesture. After testing my app on my Watch, I realised that the button is less responsive with onTapGesture and onLongpressGesture. I can visibly see the button being pressed down, but it only sometimes processes action 1 and action 2. Is anyone having a similar experience, what is the workaround?

```
 Button(action: {
                  // action 1
                }) {
                  Image(systemName: "checkmark")

                    .onTapGesture (count:1){
                      // action 1
                  }

              .onLongPressGesture {
                // action 2
              }
            }
```

Comment: I just got the same problem lol...
After checking the below answer, I still don't know how to solve it. : - /

Answer (score 1):

don't use button.

```
Image(systemName: "checkmark")
.onTapGesture {
    // action 1
}
.onLongPressGesture {
    // action 2
}
```

Or add simultanous gesture to button

```
Button(action: {
    print("tap")
}) {
    Image(systemName: "trash")
}.simultaneousGesture(LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 1, maximumDistance: 10).onEnded({ (b) in
    print("long")
}))
```

warning, 'extra' tap will follow each long event ...

You can play with gesture mask, let say

```
Button(action: {
    print("tap")
}) {
    Image(systemName: "trash")
}.simultaneousGesture(LongPressGesture().onChanged({ (b) in
    print("long change", b)
})
    .onEnded({ (b) in
    print("long end")
}), including: .gesture)
```

prints

```
long change true // on tap
```

or

```
// on long press
long change true
long end
```

but no "tap" !